# How to get the primary key of last updated record in MYSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

We know if the primary key is autocrement, SELECT statement could return what I need.
What about UPDATE?

Using last_insert_id is thread safe?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the context? Shouldn't the update ID be known to you anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using last_insert_id is thread safe?

It's *connection*-safe, which is probably what you mean. From [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> The ID that was generated is
>   maintained in the server on a
>   *per-connection basis*. This means that
>   the value returned by the function to
>   a given client is the first
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` value generated for
>   most recent statement affecting an
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` column *by that client*.
>   This value cannot be affected by other
>   clients, even if they generate
>   `AUTO_INCREMENT` values of their own.
>   This behavior ensures that each client
>   can retrieve its own ID without
>   concern for the activity of other
>   clients, and without the need for
>   locks or transactions.

(Their emphasis.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think last_insert_id will help you.  Your best bet is to make a select statement that is the same as your update, and parse the results.

Answer (score 0):

For this you create a new table actiontrack and if update query is run then insert a new record in this table

and then fetch a record in this action table using action id desc

or

take a timestamp field in the table and if update query is run then also update the timestamp field

then fetch the latest new timestamp field

Comment: what is an Action Track... Google doesn't reveal much

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve that unless you have a `MODIFIED_DATE` sort of column that you revisit in every *update* of the record to keep track of your last modification date in order to *order* on that.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you have to do two operations in order to achieve this.

Best solution I can think as of now,
a) select PK from table with same where condition which you are going to update.
b) update records with PK returned.

All other solution may fail at some point.

Answer (score 0):

`last_insert_id()` does not return the id of the recently updated row, it only returns the id of the last inserted row

With that your option would be to `select` it first and if it doesnt exist `insert` it and you can use `last_insert_id()` , if it exists `update` it using the `id` returned from your first `select`